# Unity / How to access my screen pixels outside of unity?

Tags: unity, screen

I want to run unity in background and get the pixel colors of my screen.
i didnt find anything on the assetstore or somewhere else that could make that possible.

Texture.ReadPixels()
also does only work for the game camera

What is the way to solve this?

Comment: Do you essentially mean be able to look at a user's monitor when your game is minimised? Have you searched for screencap software and how it works?

Comment: Unity seems like an odd choice for this. Can you tell us more about how sampling colours from the screen features in your game? If it's not specifically the game-y parts of the mechanic you need help with, then you might find more knowledge about this topic on our [general programming sister site StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). I can't think of many games that use this kind of interaction, but it's often used in productivity software, so devs from that background may have better leads to offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allright, so ive found this here:

https://github.com/hecomi/uDesktopDuplication

With that you can read pixels while running unity on background. :-)
Just wanted to share this.

Comment: Please consider summarizing the main ideas of the technique you're linking to (eg. the use of the [Desktop Duplication API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3ddxgi/desktop-dup-api)) as part of your answer itself. That way even if the GitHub repository is taken down or becomes unavailable, your answer will still help future readers work toward a solution.

Comment: Also, flag your answer as the answer so your question get's that checkmark of having been served

Comment: yeah.... im sorry but I have no idea how that guy has done it actually :-(
So... I wish I could summarize the main ideas of the technique, but I lack to time to inspect it :/

But as far as I got it its some windows-duplication-api thingy.

Can you like... upload that thing somewhere here? ^^"